# Vertex snapping not working in edit mode. Proportional editing is off

Tags: armature, edit-mode, pose-mode, snapping

Blender 3.6.2

I am unable to vetex snap in edit mode to any vertex belonging to the same mesh. Before the screenshot I had other separate objects in the background and it will snap to their vertices just fine until I turned off the exclude or the include non edited. I finally just focused on the single mesh and hid everything else. Proportional editing is off, so what am I missing that is keeping this from snapping? It is driving me insane

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is unclear which part of the mesh you want to snap onto what? In your screenshot I can only see (if I interpret the colors correctly, my UI is on default colors) selected vertices. What do you want them to snap to?

Comment: -To quote myself: "any vertex belonging to the same mesh.". 
-Sorry for the color difference. I forgot that default is orange. In this shot the green is the only vert selected.

Comment: I read that quote, but to me the colors looked like all vertices could be selected and green only showed this was the active vertex. And the problem would have simply been, if all vertices are selected and you move them, there is no vertex left to snap to. That's why I was asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to edit this mesh that is attached to an armature, and that armature was in a none T-pose. I switched it back to default pose and it seems to work there just fine.

Comment: Without these informations about your mesh the question is unanswerable for other users... and since only judging from the screenshot there could be other reasons for your issue, someone with one of those issues will not benefit from this question. However if you made clear what is going on in your specific case and maybe adding tags that indicate it is also about armatures and posing, other people with your problem might find this answer quicker if they knew what this is about.

Comment: I didn't understand it at the time. Searching with my limited knowledge and not knowing the association seems to have meant that shitty google didn't point me to any forums that made the association. Finally, I found something that did and went out of my way to log this with my answer now with new text with new keywords; the site will not let me click the check mark for 2 days. I wasn't aware I could add more tags. I will update it all tomorrow when I can select my own as the answer.